# Help needed with MySQL query to join data spanning multiple tables with data used as column names

Tags: sql, mysql

I need a little help putting together a SQL query that will give me the following resultsets:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7991d3bdd3.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/7991d3bdd3.png)

and

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/39135e4196.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/39135e4196.png)

The data model looks like this:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bff4321b54.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/bff4321b54.png)

The tricky part for me is that the columns to the right of the "Product" in the resultset aren't really columns in the database but rather key/value pairs spanned across the data model.

Table data is as follows:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e3b1a1c80c.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/e3b1a1c80c.png)

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/cbb473d1af.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/cbb473d1af.png)

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8c07b6d1d6.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8c07b6d1d6.png)

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/45a322a155.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/45a322a155.png)

My apologies in advance for the image heavy question and the image quality.  This just seemed like the easiest way to convey the information.  It'll probably take someone less time to write the query statement to achieve the results than it did for me to assemble this question.

By the way, the "product_option" table image is truncated but it illustrated the general idea of the data structure.

The MySQL server version is 5.1.45.

Comment: Copy + paste doesn't work on images. :(

Comment: Your question title is totally redundant and doesn't give any hint of what the question is about.

Comment: Holy cow!  Another cautionary example of why EAV tables are a fool's bet.
The correct answer is to first **normalize the database!**   I could crack the workaround in MSSQL but my MySQL's a little rusty.

Comment: Reporting is where you find out if your database schema is well designed. When you have to write a crosstab query just to get the most basic information, it is an indication that the database schema is not designed well for the business problems it needs to solve.

Comment: First and foremost, you're right the title does suck.  My apologies for that.  I was throwing up a Hail Mary.

I knew the data design might take a few hits and I'm open to suggestions.  Brock how would you design this simple little model?  I'm not familiar with the EAV tables statement.  And Thomas I agree with you, this reporting issue has definitely exposed a design flaw.  How would you solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe a RDF store would work better :p

Answer (score 4):

They're both standard pivot queries, but they have to be separate on account of different column headings and one has more columns than the other.

### Query 1:

---

```
   SELECT p.name AS product,
          MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Brand' THEN po.value ELSE NULL END) AS Brand,
          MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Size' THEN po.value ELSE NULL END) AS Size,
          MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Color' THEN po.value ELSE NULL END) AS Color,
          MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Material' THEN po.value ELSE NULL END) AS Material,
          MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Sole' THEN po.value ELSE NULL END) AS Sole
     FROM PRODUCT p
     JOIN CATEGORY c ON c.category_id = p.category_id
                    AND c.name = 'shoe'
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_OPTION po ON po.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN OPTION o ON o.option_id = po.option_id
 GROUP BY p.name
```

### Query 2:

---

```
   SELECT p.name AS product,
          MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Make' THEN po.value ELSE NULL END) AS Make,
          MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Model' THEN po.value ELSE NULL END) AS Model,
          MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Color' THEN po.value ELSE NULL END) AS Color,
          MAX(CASE WHEN o.name = 'Doors' THEN po.value ELSE NULL END) AS Doors
     FROM PRODUCT p
     JOIN CATEGORY c ON c.category_id = p.category_id
                    AND c.name = 'car'
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_OPTION po ON po.product_id = p.product_id
LEFT JOIN OPTION o ON o.option_id = po.option_id
 GROUP BY p.name
```

Comment: Would it be possible to avoid using static calls to data like o.name = 'Make' and dynamically generate the resultset from a simple category_id?

Comment: @gurun8: Yes, but only using dynamic SQL, which means using MySQL's Prepared Statement syntax: http://rpbouman.blogspot.com/2005/11/mysql-5-prepared-statement-syntax-and.html

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
select p.name as [Product]
       , MAX(select value from product_option where product_Id = p.product_id and and option_Id = 1) as Brand
       , MAX(select value from product_option where product_Id = p.product_id and and option_Id = 2) as Size
       , MAX(select value from product_option where product_Id = p.product_id and and option_Id = 3) as Color
       , MAX(select value from product_option where product_Id = p.product_id and and option_Id = 4) as Material
       , MAX(select value from product_option where product_Id = p.product_id and and option_Id = 4) as Sole
 from product p
GROUP BY p.name
```

Same principle for second table

Comment: Done, but you can edit it yourself.  You'll want to correct the MAX stuff - I'm out the door.

Comment: Thanks OMG! I'll have a look later and edit the max part, cheers!